# XSLT in order of the XML structure given

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a structure of XML as below :

```
<root>
   <node1> 
         <name>John</name> 
   </node1>
   <node1> 
         <name>Rita</name> 
   </node1>
   <node2> 
         <city>Irvine</city> 
   </node2>
   <node1> 
         <name>Kate</name> 
   </node1>
   <node2> 
         <city>LA</city> 
   </node2>
<root>
```

XSLT is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">   
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Details>
      <xsl:for-each select="/root">       
          <xsl:for-each select="node1">
                <xsl:if test="name!=''"  >
                   <Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                   </Name>
                </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:for-each select="node2">
                <xsl:if test="city>!=''"  >
                   <City>
                    <xsl:value-of select="city>"/>
                   </City>
                </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </Details>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need an output as:

```
    <Details xmlns:PP="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/Details.xsd">
      <Name>John</Name>
      <Name>Rita</Name>
      <City>Irvine</City>
      <Name>Kate</Name>
      <City>LA</City>
    </Details>
```

But i am getting the below output:

```
    <Details xmlns:PP="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/Details.xsd">
      <Name>John</Name>
      <Name>Rita</Name>
      <Name>Kate</Name>
      <City>Irvine</City>
      <City>LA</City>
    </Details>
```

Kindly please help on this.

Comment: Your input is not well-formed, and your XSLT produces an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLt 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <Details>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*"/>
    </Details>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
    <Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </Name>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="city">
    <City>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </City>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i am not able to get the desired output using this, may be because of the  node1,node2 missing.

Comment: @Jyothsna I don't understand what you're saying. You can see this working here: http://xsltransform.net/ncntCRQ Note that I had to correct `<root>` to `</root>.`

Comment: Hi Michael,  I am sorry i have not exposed my original code, when i applied this to my code it didnt work, i tried by changing few lines, it worked. Thank you so much for your help. I really admire the quick response that you have given.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `xslt` template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">   
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <Details>
          <xsl:for-each select="/root/*/*/.">
                <xsl:copy-of select= "."/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Details>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I believe they want to rename city --> City, name --> Name.

Comment: well OP doesn't say that. I believe they only care about order.

Comment: I want it in the order, it is considering all the lines with name first and then the city, i need them in the order that i have specified in the XML.

Comment: YES! try the xslt snippet I gave in answer. It will work fine for you